# What is difference between prototype shadowing and prototype chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me understand that what is prototype shadowing, also how it differs from prototype chaining, i have being reading many articles regarding same but that didn't clear my concepts.

Comment: Prototype shadowing is when a property or method conceals access to an equivalently named one on a superclass, and prototype chaining is simply jargon for prototypal inheritance in object-oriented programming. FYI, I didn't downvote.

Comment: There's a decent explanation available in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function Person(name) {
 this.firstName = 'default';
 this.lastName = 'default';
}

let joan = new Person()
joan.firstName = 'joan';

console.log(joan.firstName);//joan
console.log(joan.lastName);//default
```

I have my own way of understanding `Prototype`. Basically try to understand it as, prototype gives you the power to access and map the attribute/property of any object.

The code demonstrated above, while doing a logging of `joan.firstName`, it checks if `firstName` property exists in the object `joan`, since yes, it shadows the prototype and print `joan`.

As for when logging `joan.lastName`, first it check if property `lastName` is exist in object `joan`, obviously no, so the engine using `prototype chaining` to traverse to `Person` object and get the value from it.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with prototypes. `this.firstName` and `joan.firstName` are the exact same property. You're not shadowing anything here, you're just assigning a different value to an object property. Prototypes literally need `.prototype.` (or `class`), what you do in the constructor function is *not* the prototype.

Comment: If I do a checking on `Person.prototype.hasOwnProperty(joan.firstName)`, it returns `false`

Comment: Isn't that supposed to mean that the attribute `firstName` is not exist in joan?

Comment: `Person.prototype.hasOwnProperty(joan.firstName)` tests whether the `Person.prototype` object has a property named `default` (or `joan`, depending on the value of `joan.firstName`…).

Comment: What you want is `joan.hasOwnProperty('firstName')`. (Which is `true`, because `firstName` is a property directly on `joan`, *not* its prototype.)